# reorder column in mysql

Tags: mysql

How can I select `column b` in a random order using MySQL?

For example, given values:

```
qw
we
rt
sd
```

after random order may be it become:

```
we
qw
sd
rt
```

Comment: via a SELECT statement? if so, use RAND.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need random order? Try this:

```
SELECT b FROM your_table
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, use "ORDER BY" in your SQL statement.

For more reference, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reorder the values in the table. Your ordering should be done at the time you query it:

```
SELECT b FROM tbl ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is barely a question, but if I infer correctly, you want to select the values of `column b` in a random order.

```
SELECT `column b` FROM `your_table` ORDER BY RAND();
```